# Can I prevent a .js file from loading on certain site pages to stop browser errors?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, joomla

I am getting a heavy load of errors because a Jquery .js file I have embedded in the Joomla index.php page.  These errors are just browser errors but if I do any scrolling they just pile up.

The specific error says this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null js-snippets.min.js:11
(anonymous function) js-snippets.min.js:11
f.event.dispatch js-snippets.min.js:4
h.handle.i js-snippets.min.js:4
```

The page it is supposed to work on is fine and does not see this error.

I guess I could put the .js file reference in each html page that I need it for but I hate doing that.  Isn't it better for the file to be in one single place?

In any event if I could prevent the .js file from loading on page(s) it would be ideal.

Here is a [link to the site in questions.](http://curtisj.trafficflo.net/index.php/residents)

Comment: `reference in each html page` ... are you sure you're using Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small script to test whether your js is needed and inject it only if needed. Or better: adapt the .js so it tests by itself whether it is needed.

Comment: how can I adapt it to see if it is needed?

Comment: look at line 11 of js-snippets.min.js to see what makes the code fail, or toggle 'catch all exceptions' on in your favorite JS debugger.